# Intermittent time out issues between MongoDB Atlas and AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm a bit desperate on this issue: We are running AWS Lambda for our API that talks to a MongoDB cluster on MongoDB Atlas (M20). To prevent creating a fresh connection on every Lambda invocation, we follow this pattern: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/best-practices-connecting-to-aws-lambda/ to cache the connection during the lifetime of the Lambda container. We have a slight variation of it:

```
async function getProdDB() {
  const url = `mongodb+srv://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}@xxxxx-yyyy.zzzzz.net?retryWrites=true`

  if (!cachedDb || !cachedDb.serverConfig.isConnected()) {
    cachedClient = await MongoClient.connect(
      url,
      { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }
    )
    cachedDb = cachedClient.db(process.env.DB_NAME)
  }

  return cachedDb
}
```

that also checks if we are connected. Now this works 98% of the time, but every now and then our Lambda invocation times out. We tried to diagnose a bit:

1. We changed time out limits for Lambda from 6s to 30s/60 seconds, and Lambda functions would still time out now and then. Mongo never threw an error, it was always Lambda finishing the invocation due to TimeoutError
2. In case of successfull and unsuccessfull invocations, `cachedDB.serverConfig.isConnected()` returned rue`
3. The part of the business logic that causes the timeout is the query to MongoDB itself, common MongoDB operations like `findOne` or `updateOne` on very small collections (tops 100 documents)
4. We tried upgrading our MongoDB driver on NodeJS from `3.3.1` to `3.3.5` following https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/8180 (we are not using mongoose though, just the official mongodb NodeJS driver) and the issue persisted
5. We tried querying our MongoDB cluster directly via a NodeJS script that uses the same version of our driver, and out of several thousand queries, not a single time out issue occured. So we concluded, that the issue is not our cluster itself, but rather the connection.
6. Functions that are called very frequently do not time out more often than functions that are getting called regularly, but less frequent. It seems, that our cached connection to MongoDB is somehow becoming stale even though returning `true` when calling `isConnected()` and can't be reused after the Lambda container remained open for a while without an invocation. We are using the default timeouts: https://scalegrid.io/blog/understanding-mongodb-client-timeout-options/
7. Checked MongoDB log entries on Atlas - nothing suspicious there
8. Stopping chaching the DB connection solved the issue but makes most API calls 2-3 times slower, and we still would like to understand the root of the problem

Did anybody face a similar issue or can suggest how we can proceed with debugging this issue efficiently?

Comment: If I this statement :: `In case of successful and unsuccessful invocations` is about lambda invocation - then do you mean irrespective of lambda timeout or success- DB call is happening ? Also I would say change this `(!cachedDb || !cachedDb.serverConfig.isConnected())` to `(!cachedDb && !cachedDb.serverConfig.isConnected())`, Please try & test whether a connection is getting created every time or it's using cached connections. Also does timeouts happening on same code or from different code - Usual lambda timeouts can happen when a `callback()` is not properly called.

Comment: cont'd : In your case if same query executed using a client or general code does execute in fewer ms shouldn't take much time causing lambda timeouts !! Also usual lambda timeout is 15mins max, but ideal is 15-30sec depends on operation- your case is good enough..

Comment: regarding your first comment: Yes, `true` is returned from the `cachedDb.serverConfig.isConnected()` in cases where the database returns a results from the query to lambda and also when it doesn't, causing the lmabda invocation to be stuck in the call to the database and timing out after the set timeout limit of lambda

Comment: The proposed changed to the condition doesn't make sense to me. We want to check if their is either no cached connection yet or we have one, but it is not connected. Using an AND here would not work, e.g. when you have a `cachedDB` but it not connected, the condition would be falsy and no attempt to create a new connection would happen.

Comment: Yes, the exact same code sometimes executes correctly, and sometimes times out. When the code is executed fine on lambda, the lambda invocations take 20-30 ms on average to execute. The same functions time out sometimes as described, no matter how high we set the timeout limit in Lambda.

Comment: Yes, we are always creating a new connection on a cold start of lambda and afterwards reusing it.

Comment: We are facing the same issue. If you have found a solution, please answer it here.

Comment: upgraded mongo driver to 3.5.4, still seeing the issue.

Comment: Did you ever get a resolution on this? We are seeing this same issue.

Comment: are there any updates guys? this seems to be such an annoying problem that everyone who uses aws lambda + mongodb has come across this but no one has solved it yet :(

Answer (score 1):

Our company is currently using the same architecture (Lambda -> MongoDB Atlas Cluster) with over 500 lambdas and we are not seeing any issues with the connections timing out. We're using version 3.6 of the Node.js driver.

Here is the code we are using:

```
public static async connect(url?: string): Promise<Db> {
    /** If MongoDB is already connected, return that */
    if (this.cachedDb && this.client && this.client.isConnected())
      return Promise.resolve(this.cachedDb);

    /** Check for MongoURL in env if not provided */
    const mongoUrl: string = url || process.env.MONGO_CONNECTION_URL || '';

    this.client = await MongoClient.connect(mongoUrl, {
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      ignoreUndefined: true,
    });

    this.cachedDb = this.client.db();

    return Promise.resolve(this.cachedDb);
  }
```

We then use the cached db and clients later on the same `MongoClient`:

```
/**
 * MongoDB Client Class
 */
class MongoDbClient {
  private static cachedDb: Db | null = null;
  private static client: MongoClient | null = null;

  /**
   * Connects to a MongoDB database instance
   *
   * @param url The MongoDB connection string
   *
   * @returns An instance of a MongoDB database
   */
  public static async connect(url?: string): Promise<Db> {
    /** If MongoDB is already connected, return that */
    if (this.cachedDb && this.client && this.client.isConnected())
      return Promise.resolve(this.cachedDb);

    /** Check for MongoURL in env if not provided */
    const mongoUrl: string = url || process.env.MONGO_CONNECTION_URL || '';

    this.client = await MongoClient.connect(mongoUrl, {
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      ignoreUndefined: true,
    });

    this.cachedDb = this.client.db();

    return Promise.resolve(this.cachedDb);
  }

  /**
   * Retrieves the first document that matches a filter condition
   *
   * @param collectionName The name of the collection to search
   * @param filter The filter to search for
   * @param options MongoDB find one option to include
   *
   * @returns The first document that matches the filter condition
   */
  public static async findOne<T>(
    collectionName: string,
    filter: FilterQuery<T> = {},
    options: FindOneOptions<T extends T ? T : T> = defaultDocumentOptions
  ): Promise<T | null> {
    const db = await this.connect();
    return db.collection<T>(collectionName).findOne<T>(filter, options);
  }
}
```

The difference I noticed is that we are checking to see if the [`MongoClient`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.7/api/MongoClient.html#isConnected) is connected versus the `Db`. This has since been deprecated and [handled internally](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/4.0/src/operations/connect.ts) by the driver in versions 4+ using this code:

```
// If a connection already been established, we can terminate early
  if (mongoClient.topology && mongoClient.topology.isConnected()) {
    return callback(undefined, mongoClient);
  }
```

Another thing that could be happening is that the Lambda is occasionally being destroyed/corrupted. This is unpreventable and [normal behavior for Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-context.html), which is why [AWS recommends having a retry strategy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-retries.html) built into your program.

Note that even the AWS SDK has a retry strategy per their documentation:

> Clients such as the AWS CLI and the AWS SDK retry on client timeouts, throttling errors (429), and other errors that aren't caused by a bad request.